# Can I monitor progress of spacy parsing?

Tags: python, nlp, monitoring, spacy, spacy-3

I have a simple program to process English text with spacy and output some of the info about the tokens. For a big text it takes a long time for spacy to process it. Is there a way to see how far the processing has progressed ideally as a percentage? I'm not using my own models, just ones provided by spacy.

```py
import spacy

// load big text file into `text` variable

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
nlp.max_length = len(text)+1
doc = nlp(text)

// output info
```

Answer (score 0):

In general I would not advice to parse the entire text as one big blob of text and instead try to split it into smaller paragraphs first.

For example, [you can split at every `\n\n`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69878446/18189622) first.

Then you can hand multiple documents to SpaCy at once using `nlp.pipe()`, which you can [use a tqdm progress bar on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68158813/18189622).

Alternatively, you can [create batches within the document and then concatenate the results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429869/batch-running-spacy-nlp-pipeline-for-large-documents).

Comment: Can you elaborate why you would generally advise splitting texts into smaller paragraphs? Don't you lose some accuracy by parsing each paragraph in isolation? I guess normally it might not reduce accuracy, but maybe sometimes it would, such as when there are bullet points which appear as separate paragraphs? In my case the user may be supplying text from PDFs or OCR which could have page breaks as \n\n inside sentences.